# C++ Object Serialization

Tags: c++, serialization

I need to get the byte stream of an object in C++. 
I could not find a way to do this without using serialization.

```
NodeEntry *one = new NodeEntry("mani", 34, 56.3);

ofstream rofs("result.ros", ios::binary);
rofs.write((char *)&one, sizeof(one));
rofs.close();

// now we read the file into object!!    
ifstream ifsr("result.ros", ios::binary);
NodeEntry *oner;
ifsr.read((char *)&oner, sizeof(oner));
```

Is there any other workaround? I don't want to send this object through the network or store it on hard disk. I just want to get the byte stream of object **one** without actually creating the file.

In other word I need to create a byte stream of object **one** and store it somewhere (like in an ostream), then passing these bytes to another method and re-construct the object from these bytes.

I would appreciate if you give me a hint on this.

Comment: What do you mean by the "byte stream"?  What do you intend to do with it?

Comment: Check out some serialization frameworks like msgPack or Thrift. The approach you describe here will not work for strings or complex data structures.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: I need the byte streams to do some calculation (for Rabin's Algorithm).

Comment: @DvirVolk: But the above code worked for object **one**. As far as I know serialization in C++ does not work for vectors or lists.

Comment: There is no portable way of doing this in the general case. (The code you posted does not work, you have not allocated storage for `oner` btw.)

Comment: your code may have worked by accident because you deserialized it in the same process space, so all the pointers remained in place. but you will never be able to serialize it across processes.

Comment: You could just case your object pointer as a pointer to an array of bytes, but padding or other platform-specific differences may make the results unpredictable.

Comment: /* is it correct? */
rofs.write((char *)&one, sizeof(one));

/* i think it should be: */
rofs.write((char *)one, sizeof(NodeEntry));

Comment: @KiswonoPrayogo: what the code above do is saving the address of the object one in a file. Then reading the file and copying the address to object oner. Due to the fact that these operations are done within a single process and in a single method, object oner point to object one and thus we have access to it through oner variable.
you are right if the contents of object one should be stored in the file, but it seems that it is not possible to do it as "Dvir Volk" mentioned before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do realize that you're writing the *address* of `one`, right?  Basically what you've written is the equivalent of:

```
NodeEntry** doublePtr = &one;
oner = *doublePtr;
```

If you wanted to write the contents of the object, you'd pass `one` to `write` and `sizeof(NodeEntry)`, but as Dvir Volk mentions, this won't work right (or at least probably not how you want it to) with anything that contains a pointer.

Anyway, I like [Google's Protocol Buffers](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf/) for serializing objects.  It's a far more robust solution to your problem.

Also, "byte stream" makes no sense... do you mean the raw memory of the object in bytes?